# how to remove error: Parameter 'view' is not used in either this method or any of its derived methods

Tags: android

I'm reviewing my code with Android Studio, and it says that:

Parameter 'view' is not used in either this method or any of its derived methods

All I have is a Layout in my layout.xml which has an onClick method

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/list_background"
                android:paddingEnd="40dp"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:paddingStart="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:onClick="didClickPrivacy"
                >
```

such method is like this

```
public void didClickPrivacy(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewer.class);
    intent.putExtra(URL_TO_LOAD, URL_PRIVACY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
```

it opens a new Activity sending parameters, I'm not using the view because I don't need it, but it marks that error, if I try to remove the parameter, then I can't call my method from my XML. how to remove this error???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of ways to solve these warnings

- Using suppress like suggestion
- Using `view`, eg `Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WebViewer.class);`
- Using `data binding`

I prefer use [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) so your code will look like.

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/list_background"
            android:paddingEnd="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:paddingStart="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:onClick="${() -> handlers.didClickPrivacy()}"
            >


public class Handlers {
    public void didClickPrivacy(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewer.class);
        intent.putExtra(URL_TO_LOAD, URL_PRIVACY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a warning and you can ignore it